# Samsung Gear deep link to Google Play Store

Tags: android, deep-linking, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am developing Samsung Gear (Tizen native) app, which also has companion app for Android. Companion app is needed to fully use the wearable app, so I need to place deep link to the Android app inside the wearable app to meet Samsung's wearable apps requirements.

The problem is, I cannot figure out how to do this, I did not find anything besides the SAP, which has no point here, because that would mean there has to be some app in Android phone to communicate over SAP.

I tried to open the web browser with URL to Play Store via appcontrol, but it just produces one log line that tells there is no app to process request (I naively thought it would somehow open the browser on phone, but it does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deep link is pulled from the Gear app by Gear Manager after installing the app on the watch. The Gear Manager app on the phone then performs the deep link to the app store. You need to add a meta-data line to config.xml or tizen-manifest.xml containing the deep link. Should look something like:

```
<tizen:metadata key="master_app_playstore_deeplink" value="playstore deeplink URL"/>
```

[See Here](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/web-companion/configuration)

Comment: Your link is dead. Also can't find any information for .NET Tizen apps.